# How can I add a custom function inside the class annotated with the 'freezed' library?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have defined a class like this and annotated with the [freezed library](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed).

```dart
@freezed
@immutable
abstract class CommentMediaAttachmentModel with _$CommentMediaAttachmentModel {
  const factory CommentMediaAttachmentModel({
    final String type,
    final String mediaUrl,
    final int width,
    final int height
  }) = _CommentMediaAttachmentModel;

  bool isAnimated() {
    return type == 'ANIMATED';
  } 
}
```

I'd like to add a quick function `isAnimated` to determine the `type` variable, but on compilation, it doesn't allow me to do so:

```
lib/presentation/comment/model/comment_attachment_model.freezed.dart:292:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_$_CommentMediaAttachmentModel' is missing implementations for these members:
 - CommentMediaAttachmentModel.isAnimated
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
```

Upon checking the generated class `_$_CommentMediaAttachmentModel`, `isAnimated` function isn't implemented. How can I achieve that?

Edit: Below is the code of `_$_CommentMediaAttachmentModel`.
I'm not sure why I cannot paste that snippet to SO, it just said the code is malformed. I will use a screen capture instead:
[image]

Comment: give use the code of the 
_$CommentMediaAttachmentModel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To manually define methods/properties on the class, [as stated in freezed documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#custom-getters-and-methods), you have to define a single private constructor:

```
@freezed
@immutable
abstract class CommentMediaAttachmentModel with _$CommentMediaAttachmentModel {
  const CommentMediaAttachmentModel._(); // Added constructor
  const factory CommentMediaAttachmentModel({
    final String type,
    final String mediaUrl,
    final int width,
    final int height
  }) = _CommentMediaAttachmentModel;

  bool isAnimated() {
    return type == 'ANIMATED';
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically You need to implement `isAnimated` inside the `_$CommentMediaAttachmentModel` too. because it is a `mixin` of the `abstract` class.

Comment: Freezed uses code generation, and `_$CommentMediaAttachmentModel` is a generated class.  Any modifications to the class itself would be undone whenever the OP runs `build_runner` again for any reason.

Comment: Error you have is not the error of the `@freezed` it is an error of the abstract class and asking you to implement `isAnimated` function inside the `_$CommentMediaAttachmentModel`